# Is dynamic language change in iOS app allowed?

Tags: ios, localization

Is dynamic language change in iOS app allowed? Normally the language is set basing on the device's language. But if I add settings in my app that would allow changing the language without changing the language of the device, will my app be rejected by Apple?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many apps (mostly games) does it. Your app shouldn't get rejected, but it's not so welcomed by the users. It's generally much better to have the language setting handled by the system. It's much more convenient for the end user. I was trying to find anything in Apple Guidelines but didn't notice anything interesting on the topic.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also couldn't find anything saying about Apple not recommending this.

Comment: @jonaszmclaren Glad to help :)

Comment: "It's generally much better to have the language setting handled by the system." - I think, the users like to do what ever they feel like, for some apps they want English, for others Turk, what the user wants is a choice - you can always add in setting "System default".